# Pylint explanation of R1712

Tags: pylint

I'm getting this error when using pylint on my project

consider-swap-variables (R1712):
Consider using tuple unpacking for swapping variables You do not have to use a temporary variable in order to swap variables. Using "tuple unpacking" to directly swap variables makes the intention more clear.

and my code is

```
init_acc_src = acc_src
```

can some one can explane how should it be done correctly based on pylint?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are swapping variables here, probably we'd need to see more than one line.
I've created a dummy example

```py
a = 5
b = 7
c = a
a = b
b = c
```

which also raises in line 3 (`c=a`)

```
dummy_swap.py:3:0: R1712: Consider using tuple unpacking for swapping variables (consider-swap-variables)
```

The recommended way of swapping variables in python is the much shorter

```py
a = 5
b = 7
a, b = b, a
```